# Using Options Menu in a multi-Fragment Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, options-menu

I have a `FragmentActivity` which hosts a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. The pager contains multiple instances of the same fragment, in order that the user can swipe between the items in a list. I want to be able to provide the user with an options menu which will act only on the visible item.

For example, I have a list of images displayed in imageviews inside fragments. I want an option menu item allowing the user to set the image as their wallpaper.

At the moment when I try this, when `onPrepareOptionsMenu` is called, the code is called in multiple fragments (usually the current + next one). The same when an item is selected. This causes the wrong image to be set as the wallpaper.

How can I prevent the options menu triggering for more than the currently visible fragment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was to use the `setOnPageChangeListener` method of the `ViewPager` in order to keep track of which `Fragment` index was currently visible with the `onPageSelected` callback. You still have to get the initial index yourself, but in my case this was trivial

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the options menu callback in the activity's onOptionsItemSelected, and explicitly call the item from the correct fragment there, returning true to indicate that you've handled it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You're saying have the `onOptionsItemSelected` code in the `FragmentActivity`? But how can I then get a reference to the correct `Fragment`?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to change sethasoptions( true|false) on each fragment before populating menu. This already helped me